# How do i display the value that was inputted in the same input box?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, handlebars.js

This is my html named settings.handlebars

```
<form method="post" action="/save">
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" value="{{username}}">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

and this is my js named main.js

```
app.post('/save', function (req, res, next) {

    let configObj = {
        username: req.body.username
    }

    fs.writeFile('config.json', JSON.stringify(configObj), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send("<h4>ERROR</h4>")
        }
    });
    res.redirect("/settings")
```

as you can see I have config.json where the input value will write. now I want the inputted value to be displayed in the same input box after saving the data. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: I guess I missunderstand something, however it reads like you want to display the value in the same input-field it comes from. Should it not still be in there?

Comment: yes that is what im trying to do, i want it to display in the same input box please help me @Lain

Comment: Well no need, the input is already there :-) Anyway, you have to make the same in reverse `fs.readFile('config.json')` and put the desired value in the input-field.

Comment: i actually have readfs but i dont know how to put the desired value back to the input field @lain

Comment: What does read provide you? I assume you get an object and you merely have to set the value.. like `document.querySelector('#username').value = object.username`.